# Bootstrap column empty space vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with Bootstrap columns - there is an empty space between the columns like it's shown in the picture:

[image]

My code is straightforward - one div with class **row** for all columns and each column has class **col-xs-2**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
     .... checkboxes with labels....
    </div>
    /* col-xs-2 is repeated a few times */
</div>
```

I've read about **clearfix** on similar posts here on StackOverflow but I don't know how to apply it in my case. Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The blue box to be directly below or the red box to be the same height as the green?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to raise the blue box to be exactly under the red one. It should not be concerned that the green box has larger height...

Comment: So... you want a column 1 (with two boxes in it, red, followed by blue) and then a column 2 (with two boxes in it, green followed by brown) ?  Must all bordered boxes be the same size, even if the content isn't the same size in each box?

Comment: @GeorgeFindulov    Your problem statement says you don't like the white space, but what exactly do you want?

Comment: I said in a comment above that I need to clear the white space. I tried the @Gareth's solution and after playing for a few minutes with it I got it working

Comment: Thank you also for your assistance, @zipzit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spilt the two columns first and then start a new row like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Red box content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                blue box content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                green box content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Other box content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to play with these divs for a few minutes, but finally got it working!